# PHP not executing on web host

Tags: php, html

My web host supports PHP. I have successfully run `info.php` and get pages of stuff to prove it in my browser.

When I try to execute a tiny piece of PHP in a tiny piece of HTML, as in the following hallowed script, I see nothing at all in my browser. Why? Is there something I am supposed to do?

Note: I use RapidWeaver as my principal site generation tool.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> PHP Test Script </title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    print "Hello World!";
  ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using filename extension .php ?

Comment: What is the page extension? Does phpinfo work?

Comment: Literally nothing - view source doesn't show anything, you don't have your "php test script" window title?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your file extension is indeed `.php`, so that the web-server knows how to handle the file. Also, check your error-logs, there might be something in there if you get no output at all. You can do that in your terminal by running `php --info | grep error`. On your file-system, the error-log is stored in either `/var/log/httpd/error_log` or `/var/log/apache2/error_log` (if you're on Linux).